# g++ problem: exception not caught

Tags: c++, exception, g++

The situation is that I have a dynamic library written in C++ that is wrapped for Python by another dynamic library, also written in C++ (generated by SIP to be specific). The first dynamic library defines a function `do_raise`, which throws an exception `RaiserError`, a subclass of `std::exception`. The second dynamic library, in wrapping `do_raise`, tries to catch `RaiserError` in order to translate it to a Python exception.

Building with Visual C++, everything works as expected and `RaiserError` is caught correctly. Using g++ on Linux however, `RaiserError` is not caught. If I try to catch `std::exception` instead (`RaiserError`'s baseclass), it works. What goes wrong here? Do the two libraries have different notions of the `RaiserError` type, since it does not get recognized by the catch block?

For testing I also write a small executable which calls `do_raise` in the C++ library, and here I am able to catch `RaiserError` even with g++.

Comment: It might be useful to provide your compiler versions.

Comment: There must be differences between the real app and your test app. At least one of them is critical. From what you wrote, it's _very_ hard for us to tell.

Comment: I use one version of g++, the one shipped with Ubuntu 9.04, i.e., 4.3.3. The difference with the test app is that it is also written in C++, not Python. I have since been able to make a small Python program work, since I changed a build parameter (to do with symbol export) for the Python wrapper library. However, my real application still doesn't work, so this is another indication that the issue is down to incompatible build parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can't reliably pass C++ exceptions across module boundaries. On Windows (at least for 32-bit processes) there is a standard ABI for that, but with gcc, you're out of luck.

Comment: Hasn't GCC had a stable ABI since version for all of the 4.x series?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that GCC uses some kind of pointer to the type information and if it does not match the pointer, then the types are not the same.

This sounds like one of the cases where Microsoft C++ falls back to string comparisons of type information (slow but works). That will not help you with GCC.

You might try making sure that the exception class is not hidden and that the typeinfo is visible in the ELF .so file. Try to make sure that the type is defined in only one .so.

Edit: I just thought of this: I believe ELF dynamic linkers are just fine with multiple copies of the typeinfo symbols and will choose a single copy to use. I think you can get multiple copies though if you linked some static code or did -Bsymbolic in one of the .so or executable files.

Comment: Do you know how the relevant symbols should look in the ELF libraries? As an example I have in my real project an exception "LoadImageError". In the defining/throwing library I have these typeinfo symbols:

000b9634 V typeinfo for igmUtil::LoadImageError
000a3d5c V typeinfo name for igmUtil::LoadImageError

And in the Python wrapper library (trying to catch the exception):

000174b8 d DW.ref._ZTIN7igmUtil14LoadImageErrorE
00016540 V typeinfo for igmUtil::LoadImageError
00011e85 V typeinfo name for igmUtil::LoadImageError

Comment: Hm .. apparently it wasn't such a good idea to paste symbol table excerpts :) My noobness shows I guess. I've made a pastebin page instead: http://pastebin.com/f52cf15b1

Answer (score 1):

I haven't previously had problems catching exceptions thrown by a .so, so can't speak to the other responses I've seen here.

Something unrelated to look for is whether any of your destructors might be throwing an exception:  if you throw a new exception in a destructor while unwinding the stack throwing a first exception, your program will abort, independent of any wrapping try/catches.  With g++, the error message looks the same as if you didn't catch the first exception.  Carefully step through the unwinding of the stack to see if this might be happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

As per other answers the problem is (more then likely) missing RTTI information in the .so's.

Try appending -Wl,-E to your compiler flags, this will cause the linker to export the needed type information.

VC++ uses string compares (as opposed to pointer compares) to match types (whilst dynamic casting, catching etc), this is slower at runtime but results in smaller dll's (because of less RTTI being exported in the dll's).

This will be reliable as long as your using the same compiler to compile your shared objects (or you use the vendor-neutral ABI, as available with g++ >= 4.3).

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding -Wl,-E, it didn't do me much good though :/